# How to create a yes/no boolean field in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database, boolean, sqldatatypes, tablecolumn

What is the best practice for creating a `yes/no` i.e. `Boolean` field when converting from an `access database` or in general?

Answer (score 560, accepted):

The equivalent is a `BIT` field.

In `SQL` you use `0` and `1` to set a bit field (just as a yes/no field in Access). In Management Studio it displays as a false/true value (at least in recent versions).

When accessing the database through ASP.NET it will expose the field as a boolean value.

Comment: And if you link the table in an Access database, true will have the value -1 and false will have the value 0. 

At least in Access 2003. (This is the version I had handy that was connected to a customer's MSSQL database).

Comment: Please note that it is not exactly equivalent. If a scalar function returns a bit, you still need to test if it is 0 or 1. For example, dbo.IsReturnsBit(value) = 1

Comment: @D-Money: Yes, but you only need to do the comparison if you want to use the value in a condition. If you use the value in the result, then you should not do a comparison.

Comment: Re Mgt Studio, if you are copy+pasting data in you need to have it as True / False also, not as 1 or 0.

Comment: Then, how about the size? Is it really smaller than a tinyint or char(1)?

Comment: @Zhang it will be smaller only if you have multiple bit fields in that table - then you can fit multiple ones into one byte. If it's just one BIT field per table, then it's the same as tinyint.

Answer (score 135):

The `BIT` datatype is generally used to store `boolean` values (`0` for `false`, `1` for `true`).

Comment: Are you at all concerned that the semantics of bits and booleans are different?

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `bit` column type.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `BIT` field.

For adding a BIT column to an existing table, the SQL command would look like:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD yes_no BIT`

If you want to create a new table, you could do: `CREATE TABLE table_name (yes_no BIT)`.

Answer (score 23):

There are already answers saying use of Bit. I will add more to these answers.

You should use [bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx) for representing Boolean values.

Remarks from MSDN article.

> Bit can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.
>
> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If
> there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as
> 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are
> stored as 2 bytes, and so on.
>
> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE
> is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.
>
> Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.
>
> [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177603.aspx)

### Note: It is good practice to keep values as 1 and 0 only with data type `NOT NULL`

As Bit have values 1, 0 and NULL. See truth table for this. So plan values accordingly. It might add confusion by allowing NULL value for bit data type.

> [image]
>
> [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138029/is-there-a-boolean-data-type-in-microsoft-sql-server-like-there-is-in-mysql)

Comment: `Bit can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.` If the bit data type allows nulls, I don't have to specify NULL within the field definition? That definition makes me think `[field1] [bit] NULL` vs `[field1] [bit]` are equivalent?

Answer (score 21):

You can use the data type `bit`

Values inserted which are greater than 0 will be stored as '1'

Values inserted which are less than 0 will be stored as '1'

Values inserted as '0' will be stored as '0'

This holds true for MS SQL Server 2012 Express

Comment: @BiLaL This is common behaviour across most languages. `0` is false, any non-`0` number is true. It was also common for -1 to be the default value for true because in signed binary it has every bit set to 1. Nowadays it's very common to see 1 as the default value for true (only the least significant bit set).

Answer (score 18):

Sample usage while creating a table:

```
[ColumnName]     BIT   NULL   DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Going off the info in @Somnath Muluk's answer, wouldn't allowing for null values in this column create potential confusion, as values could be 1, 0, or null?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `BIT` field

**To create new table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Tb_Table1
(
ID              INT,
BitColumn       BIT DEFAULT 1
)
```

**Adding Column in existing Table:**

```
ALTER TABLE Tb_Table1 ADD BitColumn  BIT DEFAULT 1
```

**To Insert record:**

```
INSERT Tb_Table1 VALUES(11,0)
```

Answer (score 10):

`bit` will be the simplest and also takes up the least space. Not very verbose compared to "Y/N" but I am fine with it.

Comment: It's better I think - no need to worry about Y == y and N = n, pure true or false. Intention is totally obvious, and there are no "special" cases that single character fields invite :)

Answer (score 6):

`bit` is the most suitable option. Otherwise I once used `int` for that purpose. `1` for `true` & `0` for `false`.

Comment: Normally its used 0 for False and non-zero for True.

Comment: there are a lot of flavors or true might say a good politician  :D

Answer (score 2):

> In SQL Server Management Studio of Any Version, Use `BIT` as Data Type

which will provide you with `True` or `False` Value options. in case you want to use Only `1` or `0` then you can use this method:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleBit(
    bar int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_foo_bar CHECK (bar IN (-1, 0, 1))
)
```

But I will strictly advise `BIT` as The **BEST** Option. Hope fully it's help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) type** which can have `1` or `0`, or also `NULL` if `NULL` is allowed.

**[BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) type** converts:

- Any integer values except `0` to `1`.
- Any integer string values except `"0"` to `1`.
- `"0"` to `0`.

Then, you can create a table with **[BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) type** as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE doctor (
  id INT IDENTITY,
  name NVARCHAR(50),
  on_call BIT, -- Here
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
GO
```

Then, insert rows as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO doctor 
VALUES ("John", 1), ("Tom", 0), ("Lisa", "-23"), ("Kai", "0"), ("Bob", NULL)
GO
```

```
1> SELECT * FROM doctor
2> GO
id name on_call
-- ---- -------
 1 John       1 <- 1
 2 Tom        0 <- 0
 3 Lisa       1 <- "-23"
 4 Kai        0 <- "0"
 5 Bob     NULL <- NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

***Below the List of database where what type of datatype is use for Boolean***

-> **Oracle** -> Number(1)

-> **SQL Server** -> BIT

-> **MySql** -> BIT or  TINYINT

->**postgreSQL** -> boolean

I hope this is really helpful thanks.