# Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, types, boolean

Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?

If not, what is the alternative in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Actually, MySQL does not have a `boolean` data type.

Answer (score 624, accepted):

You could use the `BIT` datatype to represent boolean data. A `BIT` field's value is either 1, 0, or null.

Comment: Also,
It is standard practice for 0 to be construed as FALSE, 1 to be construed as TRUE and Nulls, when allowed, would be reflected as NULL.

Comment: Please note that `BIT` is not equivalent to a boolean. If a scalar function returns a `bit`, you still need to test if it is 0 or 1. For example, dbo.IsReturnsBit(value) = 1

Comment: The only downside of this is that it's not particularly user friendly. For instance, I'm displaying a datagrid of a sql table, and I'd like the users to be able to see/edit true or false, not 1 or 0.

Comment: @crclayton You can have an associative calculated column that returns true for 1 and 0 for false. Other options are using transforms for reports. This, of course, assumes your typical users who will see this are not programmers that are used to the 0/1 system.

Answer (score 108):

You may want to use the [`BIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) data type, probably setting is as `NOT NULL`:

Quoting the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx):

> **bit (Transact-SQL)**
>
> An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL.
>
> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.
>
> The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.

Answer (score 71):

#### You are looking for a `bit`.  It stores 1 or 0 (or `NULL`).

Alternatively, you could use the strings `'true'` and `'false'` in place of 1 or 0, like so-

```
declare @b1 bit = 'false'
print @b1                    --prints 0

declare @b2 bit = 'true'
print @b2                    --prints 1
```

Also, any non 0 value (either positive or negative) evaluates to (or converts to in some cases) a 1.

```
declare @i int = -42
print cast(@i as bit)    --will print 1, because @i is not 0
```

Note that SQL Server uses three valued logic (`true`, `false`, and `NULL`), since `NULL` is a possible value of the `bit` data type.  Here are the relevant truth tables -

[image]

More information on three valued logic-

[Example of three valued logic in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539243/example-of-three-valued-logic-in-sql-server/30541165#30541165)

http://www.firstsql.com/idefend3.htm

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Comment: are `true` and `false` not non-zero values?

Comment: @Malachi a zero is treated as false, and non-zero values are treated as true.  But a true evaluates to 1, and false evaluates to 0.  For example,   declare @b bit = -9;

if @b = 1 
 print 'pass' --notice how bit was set to -9, but is implicitly converted to a 1 (which = "true") and passes the if test.

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll encounter additional overhead with this method, because SQL will be converting your 'true' or 'false' to 1 or 0, respectively.

Comment: @NathanielBendinsky yes, there would be overhead if any casts are involved (not just in this situation though...)   .  I just wanted to point out that it's possible to just use True / False directly. But yes, it's more efficient to just use 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 51):

There is boolean data type in SQL Server. Its values can be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`. However, the boolean data type is only the result of a boolean expression containing some combination of [comparison operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) (e.g. `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>=`) or [logical operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx) (e.g. `AND`, `OR`, `IN`, `EXISTS`). Boolean expressions are only allowed in a handful of places including the [`WHERE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) clause, [`HAVING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause, the `WHEN` clause of a [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) or the predicate of an [`IF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) or [`WHILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) flow control statement.

For all other usages, including the data type of a column in a table, boolean is not allowed. For those other usages, the [`BIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) data type is preferred. It behaves like a narrowed-down `INTEGER` which allows only the values `0`, `1` and `NULL`, unless further restricted with a `NOT NULL` column constraint or a `CHECK` constraint.

To use a `BIT` column in a boolean expression it needs to be compared using a comparison operator such as `=`, `<>` or `IS NULL`. e.g.

```
SELECT
    a.answer_body
FROM answers AS a
WHERE a.is_accepted = 0;
```

From a formatting perspective, a `bit` value is typically displayed as `0` or `1` in client software. When a more user-friendly format is required, and it can't be handled at an application tier in front of the database, it can be converted "just-in-time" using a `CASE` expression e.g.

```
SELECT
    a.answer_body,
    CASE a.is_accepted WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS is_accepted
FROM answers AS a;
```

Storing boolean values as a character data type like `char(1)` or `varchar(5)` is also possible, but that is much less clear, has more storage/network overhead, and requires `CHECK` constraints on each column to restrict illegal values.

For reference, the schema of `answers` table would be similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE answers (
    ...,
    answer_body nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    is_accepted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
);
```

Comment: Bit really isn't a Boolean equivalent because you can't assign a Boolean expression to a bit column.  Real support would handle direct assign of logical operators to bit field, EG x = y AND z.  I like your answer the best because you explicitly point this out.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Bit` DataType in SQL Server to store boolean data.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server uses the `Bit` datatype

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Bit` datatype. It has values 1 and 0 when dealing with it in native T-SQL

Answer (score 2):

Use the `BIT` datatype to represent boolean data. A `BIT` field's value is either 1,0 or NULL.

```
create table <tablename> (
    <columnName> bit
)
```

Unless you want a threeway boolean you should add NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 like so:

```
create table <tablename> (
    <columnName> bit not null default 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `TINYINT(1)`datatype in order to store boolean values in SQL Server though `BIT` is very effective

Comment: "BIT is very effective" -> So why use `TINYINT(1)` then?

Comment: TINYINT stores only 1 Byte you can check more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: But Bit is even better as SQL can pack up to 8 of them in one byte.

Comment: I've found TINYINT(1) works better on MySQL as there BIT is a binary bit value for 1 or more bits, not an ordinal number, which is why they have BOOL as an alias for TINYINT(1). For MS-SQL/TSQL BIT is generally fine. I'd be very surprised if they bothered bit packing multiple bits in a row.

Comment: TINYINT allows the use of '+' for OR and '*' for AND in SQL Server, I suppose... could be useful sometimes.