# python pandas : how to control the constraints and indices automatically created by to_sql?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, dataframe

I am using pandas 0.16 and sqlalchemy to export data to a Microsft SQL Server 2014 database.
The dataframe to_sql method automatically creates certain constraints on the table, e.g. it creates a constraint that a boolean column must be either 0 or 1.

I suspect these constraints are slowing down the export process. Is there a way to disable them, at least temporarily (i.e. re-enabling them only after all the data is in SQL)?

Also, is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find any mention of this, neither in the pandas docs nor in the sqlalchemy.

Comment: I have just noticed that to_sql creates two duplicate constraints for each boolean field. This slows everything down.

Comment: This is also followed up here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9955

Comment: Further, pandas is a community project, so contributions to improve the documentation (or even just opening issues to explain in more detail what is lacking in the docs) are very welcome!

Comment: @Joris, it was ME who reported the bug to github. I registered under a different username, but it was me. You'll notice the github report was submitted shortly after I asked this question here

Comment: I know it was you, but still it is useful to have this link here for other people looking at this question if the discussion happens there further. And again, I really appreciate that you report such a (probable) bug! Can you provide some more details in the github issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `to_sql` writes your boolean data as 0 and 1's, is because *SQL Server has no boolean data type* (see eg [Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138029/is-there-boolean-data-in-sql-server-like-mysql)).
In such cases, SQLAlchemy by default adds those constraints to the column, as is documented in the SQLAlchemy docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Boolean

Using the possibility of overriding the default type with the `dtype` argument in `to_sql` (documented [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-data-types)), you can specify to not create this constraint:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import Boolean
df.to_sql('name', engine, dtype={'my_bool_col': Boolean(create_constraint=False)})
```

Comment: I see - thanks. So I'd need to specify the option for each boolean column? Also, the to_sql method creates two such constraints for each boolean column. One possibility is that pandas creates one and sql_alchemy creates another, but I'm not sure yet. Either way - it's wrong! For now I'm finding it less fiddly to disable or drop the constraints with a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, for now you need to specify it for each column (unless sqlalchemy provides something for that). But you can do this with eg `{col: Boolean(create_constraint=False) for col in df.select_dtypes(['bool']).columns}`. You can always report an issue for such an enhancement if you think of a way to make this easier.

Comment: For the duplicate constraint, please give some more details on the github issue. I already asked there, but it would be useful to show what you find wrong.