# SQL query returns wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column in my table named 'process' which is a BOOLEAN type and has a value NULL by default. When I set the values of 'process' of all rows to NULL and do the query

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `process` != 1
```

MySQL returns an empty result set. I also get the same result when I do

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `process` = NULL
```

Furthermore, when I use PHP to print out the rows like

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM log");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if ($row['process'] != 1)
        echo $row['time']." ".$row['event']."\n";
}
```

I don't get an empty result set.
Can anyone explain to me where the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: i believe the second query should be something like `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE process IS NULL`

Comment: Or `process<>1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of three valued logic in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539243/example-of-three-valued-logic-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fire the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `process` != 1
```

The result set is returned empty because this will look for the records which do not have value '1'. NULL is not a value

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `process` = NULL
```

This sounds completely wrong, As I have informed 'NULL' is not a value. Off couse, this is the wrong method you're trying to apply.

In nutshell, NULL is not a value, therefore it cannot equal = or not equal != anything. It is not the same as zero 0 which is a value.

Check the [like](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression) for better understand.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Why doesn't `process != 1` work? I think the only difference between the two symbols is <> is standard while != is not.

Comment: @CassieLiu In fact `!=` and `<>` are logically equivalent; there is no difference.

Comment: `NULL` is an absence of a value in terms of the database field, you can not compare null value itself. Does this make sense?

Comment: [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression) is your answer for more difference.

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava I just edited the question. Could you please take a look at it again?

Answer (score 0):

To get Record which has `NULL` value,

you should Use `isnull()` instead of column=NULL

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE ISNULL(`process`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE process IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining logical false as the boolean column being *not* equal to 1 (meaning 0 or `NULL`), then you should use this logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE process <> 1 OR process IS NULL;
```

You could also slightly consolidate the `WHERE` clause using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE COALESCE(process, 0) <> 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Null is not a Value a column can have. Its more like a state, therefor you need to write

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `process` IS NULL
```

Also you can't reverse a clause with !=, you need to use <> in that case.

Comment: Could someone please explain what is wrong with this answer? - Whoever downvoted it?