# In SQL Server, how can I use the result of a comparison operator as a logical value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to compute something in an SQL Server result set that is the result of the value of comparison operators on other columns, something like

```
select (a > 2 AND b > 2 AND (c > 2 OR or c is null)) as "Reject"...
```

I just can't find any syntax that works.

Comment: `CAST(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)`. T-SQL doesn't support boolean-typed expressions (or event `BIT` literals, for that matter), and yes, that's dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` type.  Perhaps you intend:

```
select (case when a > 2 and b > 2 and (c > 2 or c is null)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_reject
```

Comment: It *does* have a `boolean` type, you just can't select it. There are many places where `boolean` appears, such as `where`,`having`,`case`,`if`,`while`

Comment: @Charlieface: per the docs you are technically correct, which as we all know is the best kind of correct, but on the other hand the *only* place where you can find this supposed "type" is in the docs, and even they can't keep their story straight. Is there a data type named `Boolean`? [Yes](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql), also [no](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql). I prefer the "there are Boolean expressions and let's not talk about a type unless we pretend it has no explicit name" angle. YMMV.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think the "no" doc you reference refers only to data types that can be stored, selected or returned. `boolean` is still a data type. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 It's all over query plans as well if you ever look at them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN A>2 AND B>2 AND (C>2 OR CIS NULL) THEN 'REJECT'
    ELSE 'NO REJECT'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a limited concept of Booleans. They are used within logical expressions in statements like IF.. ELSE and WHILE and in WHERE clauses, but cannot be assigned to a variable or column directly. Use a CASE statement instead

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a > 2 AND b > 2 AND (c > 2 OR c IS NULL)
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS "Reject"...
```

There is a BIT data type that can be either 0 or 1 and is commonly used to store truth values.

Also, SQL Server uses a three valued logic. See: [Example of three valued logic in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539243/example-of-three-valued-logic-in-sql-server)