# Why can't I compare with the result of a comparison?

Tags: sql-server, types, boolean, operators, bit

Let's suppose I have a `table` like this: t1(c1, c2, ..., cn)

Let's further suppose that I want to `update` `c1` to `1` if `c2` equals `'v'` and to `0` otherwise. This is how I tried:

```
update t1
set c1 = (c2 = 'v');
```

My intention was to see whether `c2` equals `'v'` and assign the logical value to `c1`. This had a syntax error according to SSMS 2008, so I tried the following:

```
select c2 = 'v'
from t1;
```

It selected all the rows and showed `'v'` instead of the real value of `c2`. As you can see, I am confused partly due to the ambivalency of the `=` operator, partly because of its behavior in the `select`. Off course, the effective problems have been solved, but I wonder whether there is a clear, logical explanation to the behavior of the `=` operator experienced as described.

Comment: Did the syntax error have more text? Or just "syntax error near somethingsomething"?

Comment: There is no boolean type in T-SQL and there is no arbitrary "return 1 or 0" mechanism.  (`select token = value` tries to alias value to token)

Comment: Try `SELECT (c2 = 'v') AS x FROM t1` and tell us what happened.

Comment: `c2 = 'v'` is equivalent to `'v' as c2`. That is an alternate syntax for declaring a column alias.

Comment: @MartinSmith, this is true, but doesn't answer the question... I must admit, that I did not think about this to much before, but after testing around to place my answer below I got the feeling, that SQL Server does not support a `boolean` at all... The `BIT` seems to be a *reduced INT*... Even a scalar function returning `BIT` must be queried with `=0` or `=1`. So I think the answer is: The comparison as above simply does not have a data type which could be used elsewhere...

Comment: @Shnugo - If it was submitted as an answer then "not answering the question" would be a valid complaint. It wasn't. And yes SQL Server does not have a boolean datatype.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I'm not complaining :-) Far away from complaining... Sorry, if you got it that way...

Comment: @Shnugo - That's fine! I was just pointing out that the "but doesn't answer the question" bit is unnecessary for comments as if they do they should be answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

There is **no real boolean data type** in SQL Server. There is `BIT`, but this is just an integer value reduced to `0` and `1` and you always have to compare this with your target value.

This would not work:

```
DECLARE @bit BIT=1;
IF @bit DoSomething;
```

You'd have to use

```
IF @bit=1 DoSomething;
```

Same with `CASE WHEN @bit=1 THEN ...`

But there is a boolean actually, like we know this from `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeWhere) DoSomething;
```

But this is not a data type one could use directly... Even a *boolean* scalar function you'd declare with `RETURNS BIT` and you'd have to use the return value with a comparison against 0 or 1.

### Specialty 1

This will **not return false** but rather **fill xyz into @tst**

```
DECLARE @tst VARCHAR(100)='test';
SELECT @tst='xyz';
SELECT @tst;
```

With **paranthesis** SQL Server tries to take the value, but the comparison has no value...

```
SELECT (@tst='xyz'); --error
```

## Specialty 2

This will use **the left side as alias**

```
SELECT test=Column FROM Table;
```

### Solution with CASE

This will update just the second row

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(c1 int,c2 int, c3 int);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,1,1),(2,2,3),(4,4,4);
UPDATE @tbl SET c1=CASE WHEN c2<>c3 THEN 99 ELSE c1 END
SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

### More Examples:

These are forbidden

```
SET @bit=EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE c1=50);
SET @bit=(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE c1=50));
SET @bit=(SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE c1=50));
```

But this is allowed

```
SET @bit=CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE c1=50) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

There is a related question, you might to read further: This related quesiton covers this aspect too: [Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138029/5089204)

Comment: The problem is I do not understand the cause of the behavior I have experienced.

Comment: @LajosArpad please see my update. Other as in many languages the comparison does not return a value of data type `BIT` which you could assign somewhere. BIT returning functions must be questioned with `dbo.function()=0`. The boolean result is - but I cannot really explain this - something special...

Comment: @LajosArpad One more thought: I think, that the `BIT` is rather handled as `INT`, but reduced to `0` and `1`, that's why a bit-function must be queried with `=0` or `=1` even if one might expect, the result is the boolean value already. The *real boolean* value comes from the comparison but is not a data type one could use directly...

Comment: Very nice update! SQL Server does not have a boolean type then, since BIT is just a single-digit binary number.

Comment: @LajosArpad, just for your info: I re-wrote my answer to put all the comments and thoughts into one...