# Why we can't use SELECT 1=1 in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is so strange with

```
SELECT 1=1
```

in T-Sql ?

I'm just not able to execute it. The Editor itself says incorrect syntax but it's just a Boolean expression!
[image]

I'm amazed. Somebody please clarify.

Comment: Because SQL Server doesn't have a user-visible `boolean` data type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138029/is-there-a-boolean-data-type-in-microsoft-sql-server-like-there-is-in-mysql)

Comment: why would you be able to do that? AFAIK, the only way to write a condition in the select clause of a statement is inside a case expression. you could do this, if you really want: `SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit)`

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever please elaborate on "user-visible boolean data type"? any pointers...!

Comment: @Sunny - I mean that, of course there must be times when SQL Server is evaluating predicates and probably needs to have internal variables that store the results of those evaluations. But as a *user* of SQL Server, we have no means to declare a variable of that type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever great, thanks. that helped!