# How to set bool value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which is bool. How can I set true, false values for that? Here is my query :

```
Update [mydb].[dbo].[myTable]
SET isTrue =
(
CASE WHEN Name = 'Jason' THEN 1
END
)
```

I don't know what to write after **THEN** keyword. Should I write **1** or **true** or **1 AS BIT** or something else?

Comment: it should work any error?

Comment: the query is correct, CASE WHEN Name = 'Jason' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Boolean data type in Microsoft SQL Server like there is in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138029/is-there-a-boolean-data-type-in-microsoft-sql-server-like-there-is-in-mysql)

Comment: Use `bit` type 1 = true and 0 = false. You won't need to cast, but currently you'd be leaving "false results"  as `NULL`. So add `ELSE 0` to your `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sql server does not expose a `boolean` data type which can be used in queries.
Instead, it has a `bit` data type where the possible values are `0` or `1`.
So to answer your question, you should use `1` to indicate a `true` value, `0` to indicate a `false` value, or `null` to indicate an unknown value.

```
Update [mydb].[dbo].[myTable]
SET isTrue =
CASE WHEN Name = 'Jason' THEN 
    1
ELSE 
    0
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you added will work fine, but it will you have to take care of "FALSE" part as well otherwise it will try to enter NULL in your column. 
Do you have any default value constrain on isTrue  column?

```
Update [mydb].[dbo].[myTable]
SET isTrue =
(
   CASE WHEN Name = 'Jason' THEN 1 ELSE 0
END
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need case statement with when and else if not any condition satisfied

```
Update [mydb].[dbo].[myTable]
SET isTrue = ( CASE WHEN Name = 'Jason' 
                   THEN 1 else 0 
               END)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use IIF function of sql server**

```
DECLARE @a int = 45, @b int = 40;  
DECLARE @a int = 45, @b int = 40;  
SELECT IIF ( @a > @b, 'TRUE', 'FALSE' ) AS Result; 

Result  
--------  
TRUE  

(1 row(s) affected)
```

**For Your Problem**

```
Update [mydb].[dbo].[myTable]
SET isTrue = ( Name = 'Jason', 'TRUE', 'FALSE' )
```