# Struggling with simple boolean WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, boolean-logic

Tired brain - perhaps you can help.
My table has two bit fields:
1) `TestedByPCL` and
2) `TestedBySPC`.
Both may = 1.
The user interface has two corresponding check boxes. In the code I convert the checks to int.

```
int TestedBySPC = SearchSPC ? 1 : 0;
int TestedByPCL = SearchPCL ? 1 : 0;
```

My `WHERE` clause looks something like this:

```
WHERE TestedByPCL = {TestedByPCL.ToString()} AND TestedBySPC = {TestedBySPC.ToString()}
```

The problem is when only one checkbox is selected I want to return rows having the corresponding field set to 1 or both fields set to 1.
Now when both fields are set to 1 my `WHERE` clause requires both check boxes to be checked instead of only one.
 So, if one checkbox is ticked return records with with that field = 1 , regardless of whether the other field = 1.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: This: *when only one checkbox is selected I want to return rows having both fields set to true* and this: *if one checkbox is ticked return records with with that field true, regardless of whether the other field is true* are 2 different requirements. Will you clarify?

Comment: I clarified the question (I hope) but it looks like I have the answer from Zohar below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Second attempt (I think I've got it now):

```
WHERE ((TestedByPCL = {chkTestedByPCL.IsChecked} AND TestedBySPC = {chkTestedBySPC.IsChecked}) 
OR 
(TestedByPCL = 1 AND TestedBySPC = 1 AND 1 IN ({chkTestedByPCL.IsChecked}, {chkTestedBySPC.IsChecked})))
```

Misunderstood the question.
<strike>Change the `AND` to an `OR`:</strike>

```
WHERE TestedByPCL = {chkTestedByPCL.IsChecked} OR TestedBySPC = {chkTestedBySPC.IsChecked}
```

Also:

1. [SQL Server does not have a `Boolean` data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695199/3094533), it's closest option is a `bit` data type.
2. The usage of curly brackets suggests using string concatenations to build your `where` clause. This might not be a big deal when you're handling checkboxes but it's a security risk when handling free text input as it's an open door for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Better use parameters whenever you can.

Comment: Yes, the data type is bit. I've modified the question to match my code. With this answer though when I uncheck both boxes results are returned. I get results where either fields is zero.

Comment: Excellent! Your revision seems perfect. Sorry I wasn't clear initially.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: <pedantry>There is a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a **Boolean** data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." Using `where`, `case`, `iif`,  ... would be challenging without boolean values.</pedantry>

Comment: @HABO Well, we are developers. If we won't nitpick, who will? Of course you are correct.

Comment: @developerDan this is now pretty far from the version I wrote. You are welcome to post and accept your own answer, but please stop changing the code in mine. Thanks.