# update or case statement required

Tags: mysql

I am building a small Web app for the business using MYSQL/PHP and I can't seem to get the right SQL statement. I am very fresh to this so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a **date** column for insurance documents and I have another column titled *Current*, where I want to insert/update either a YES or NO into this column based on if the document is older than 2 years.

If i run the following:

```sql
UPDATE testdb
SET Current = 'NO' WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

This works fine but I also need if `date > ....` to return YES.
So if a new document date is entered into the DB in the future for an expired document, it will also update the current column based on the new date.
As much as I try to run them together with else, if, and - I always get errors.
Thanks

Comment: Check out this question. It should guide on querying multiple columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706196/mysql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause

Comment: why not just run another query? I like to keep SQL simple

Comment: Two updates is probably quicker

Answer (score 1):

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695199/2305594 as a guide, you should be able to do something like

```
Update testdb
SET Current =
CASE WHEN date < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR) THEN 
    'No'
ELSE 
    'Yes'
END
```