# Confusion over "p OR q", "p AND q", where "p" equal to "false", "q" equal to "unknown"

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have seen the graph below on a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138029/is-there-a-boolean-data-type-in-microsoft-sql-server-like-there-is-in-mysql)

[image]

However, I'm confused about the result of "p OR q", "p AND q", where "p" equal to "false", "q" equal to "unknown".

In the graph, the result of "p OR q" is "unknown", where "p" equal to "false", "q" equal to "unknown". But shouldn't the result be "false"?

Also, in the graph, the result of "p AND q" is "false", where "p" equal to "false", "q" equal to "unknown". But shouldn't the result be "unknown"?

Could someone tell me if I'm correct or wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `NULL` has a special semantic meaning in SQL.  `NULL` means "unknown," and therefore any logical operation which depends on the value being known is unknown.

In the case of `FALSE OR NULL`, the result is unknown, because the outcome depends on what that `NULL` value might actually be.  If that `NULL` were `TRUE`, then the expression would be `TRUE`, but if it were `FALSE`, then the expression would be `FALSE`.  Since it could be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, we therefore cannot say what the value of this expression will be, and the result is also `NULL`.

However, in the case of `FALSE AND NULL`, we *can* say what the outcome will be.  Here, since `FALSE` and *anything* must be `FALSE`, the outcome will have to be `FALSE`, even if the value on the other side of `AND` be `NULL`.

Following on this, `TRUE AND NULL` has to be `NULL`, because depending on what that `NULL` might represent (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`) the value of the overall expression would change.

Comment: Thank you so so much for the clarification. Now everything makes perfect sense!  'NULL' has to be one of the most confusing part of sql. So glad to have experts like you to help out! THanks again!

Comment: @TonyStark It's especially confusing if you're coming from a Java or .NET background, where `null` has a different behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not know about Java, but in C# nullable bool (`bool?`) implement the same logic for `|` and `&` operations.