# Find all boolean columns from all tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to find boolean column in my DB.
I already know how to get data from all my tables:

```
DECLARE @sqlText VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlText = ''
SELECT @sqlText = @sqlText + ' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + CHAR(13) FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sqlText)
```

How to display only columns that were declared as boolean (bool)?

Comment: There is no Boolean type in SQL Server. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138029/78522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Boolean [data type in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138029/78522).