# Checkbox in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a form in my application which has several text boxes and I agree checkbox. In database I have to insert the data when a users fill the form. I know how to insert data from text box and other fields but I do not know how to do it for a checkbox. How to define it in table and how to define it in insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) field for 1/0 values in sql server.

also : [How do you create a yes/no boolean field in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

In the table, supposing you're using SQL Server, you'll use the [`bit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) type. In the application, use parameters in the commands, so you can just pass a boolean value to the corresponding parameter.