# Hibernate + Spring Migration from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I recently migrated the database from **MySQL** to **SQL** Server in my project, but when performing a query on the database I get this error (Conversion from **BINARY** to **BYTE** is unsupported).

I make this changes in my project :

1. I migrate with **SSMA** the database from **MySQL** to **SQL** Server (this step is OK I have the database correctly set in my **SQL** Server)
2. I put this library (**sqljdbc4-2.0.jar**) into the folder /libs of the tomcat server (picture below)

[image]

3. I configured the **context.xml** of my tomcat server like below (all the information are correct)

[image]

4. And I change the DIALECT in the **persistence.xml** 
   [image]

The error is thrown in this line :
[image]

There is the log :

```
17:42:54.118 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
17:42:54.211 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - Ignoring PartialResultException
17:42:54.266 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        utilisateu0_.ID as ID1_62_,
        utilisateu0_.ISABSENT as ISABSENT2_62_,
        utilisateu0_.ISCONNECTED as ISCONNEC3_62_,
        utilisateu0_.LASTCONNEXION as LASTCONN4_62_,
        utilisateu0_.LOGIN as LOGIN5_62_,
        utilisateu0_.MOT_DE_PASSE as MOT_DE_P6_62_,
        utilisateu0_.emp_number as emp_numb7_62_ 
    from
        UTILISATEUR_TB utilisateu0_ 
    where
        utilisateu0_.LOGIN=?
17:42:54.276 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [admintest]
17:42:54.411 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
17:42:54.411 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - La conversion de binary en BIT n'est pas prise en charge.
17:42:54.546 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR f.p.s.b.e.CustomExceptionHandler - org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: javax.faces.FacesException: fr.percall.si.base.exception.ServiceExecutionException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener.processAction(FlowActionListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.faces.model.SelectionTrackingActionListener.processAction(SelectionTrackingActionListener.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:365)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1658)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:862)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: javax.faces.FacesException: fr.percall.si.base.exception.ServiceExecutionException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: fr.percall.si.base.exception.ServiceExecutionException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at fr.percall.si.view.habilitation.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: fr.percall.si.base.exception.ServiceExecutionException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at fr.percall.si.services.habilitation.impl.HabilitationServicesSiloImpl.login(HabilitationServicesSiloImpl.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.login(Unknown Source)
    at fr.percall.si.view.habilitation.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:126)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La conversion de binary en BIT n'est pas prise en charge.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DataTypes.throwConversionError(DataTypes.java:946)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerDTVImpl.getValue(dtv.java:1952)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.getValue(dtv.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Column.getValue(Column.java:113)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1982)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getValue(SQLServerResultSet.java:1967)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getBoolean(SQLServerResultSet.java:2091)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getBoolean(DelegatingResultSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getBoolean(DelegatingResultSet.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BooleanTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BooleanTypeDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.findByLogin(Unknown Source)
    at fr.percall.si.services.habilitation.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy192.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at fr.percall.si.view.habilitation.role.UserDetailsContextMapperImpl.mapUserFromContext(UserDetailsContextMapperImpl.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at fr.percall.si.services.habilitation.impl.HabilitationServiceImpl.login(HabilitationServiceImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.login(Unknown Source)
    at fr.percall.si.services.habilitation.impl.HabilitationServicesSiloImpl.login(HabilitationServicesSiloImpl.java:67)
    ... 89 more
```

Thanks in advance, I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This tow columns have in SQL Server the type BINARY(1) and in Java it's Boolean

Comment: To add on,  the exception says, cannot execute Query. Try to execute the query printed in the log on the SQL server Mgmt Studio. with the expected value of the placeholder '?' That should perhaps give you a clue.

Comment: @Amal I execute the query in the SQL Server Management Studio and I get the appropriate data without error

Comment: Okay. I noticed `fr.percall.si.services.habilitation.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername` in the trace. Check the types attributes of the entity being  passed in this.

Comment: @XtremeBiker got it, it's the type in SQL Server of Boolean Type (I have in SQL Server BINARY(1)) but I need to have the type BIT, please add an answer to my post I will mark it as solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SQL Server, but it looks like there's a [BIT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server) for specifying a boolean. So I guess you've gone with a wrong column type.