# Return true if column has specific value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database where the creator has used decided to use `smallint` instead of `bit` for a true/false scenario.  `False` is represented with `0`. `True` is represented with `-1`. I would like to translate this, preferably in a simpler syntax than `CASE`. Is there any way I can do something like this:

```
SELECT (column == -1) 'value_as_bool'

FROM   myTable
```

Which would (in most languages) translate the column back to a true/false column...

Comment: SQL has TRUE and FALSE as boolean values.

Comment: @jarlh I know, but the guy who created the table apparently decided to ignore this. So I'm stuck with `-1` and `0`. And there is quite a few of these columns, so my syntax would be a mess if I have to use `CASE`.

Comment: @Stephen I changed the example to make it more clear what I would like (hopefully)

Comment: @jarlh: TSQL has no boolean datatype, so `SELECT (column = -1) AS value_as_bool FROM myTable` fails with an exception.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, oops. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: I think it might work with `CAST(column * -1 AS BIT)`, but this has quite a drastical impact on the performance.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to just cast the `int` value to a `bit`. `0` will be `False` everything else `True`.

```
SELECT CAST(column As Bit) 'value_as_bool'
FROM   myTable
```

Comment: I think you are right. I am just have to live with the performance impact.

Comment: If you can change the schema you could always add a persisted computed column to your table and use that instead. You would not get any performance hit.

Comment: Single quotes are string delimiters. It's double quotes for names in standard SQL and brackets in SQL Server AFAIK. But as `value_as_bool` already is a valid name you need no delimiters at all.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it works with single quotes, but it also works without. I prefer to avoid double quotes, since the query is to be used in VBA, where double quotes will end the string...

Comment: @Noceo: Better have valid names without any kind of quotes. Using single quotes for names is (according to standard SQL) invalid has its Limits. Just try: `SELECT 'value_as_bool' FROM (SELECT CAST(column As Bit) 'value_as_bool' FROM   myTable) t`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIF function. Usage; IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )

Comment: That is simpler than `CASE`, but I have some trouble getting it to work. I have tried like this `IIF(column = -1, 1, 0)`

Comment: You should use like this `SELECT IIF(column = 0, 0, 1)` but i forgot to say that IIF comes from SQL 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In a Case, the statement would be:

Case when myTable.column = -1 then 0 else 1 end as [NAME]

You can replace 0 and 1 with FALSE and TRUE, which uses the BOOLEAN/bit type in SQL, if you wish :)

Comment: General syntax is
case when [statement with boolean output] then [value if true]
         when [statement with boolean output] then [value if true]
         when ...
         else [value if all of the above is false]
         end (possibly with 'as [#NAME#]' afterwards

Comment: How do I control the output? If I use 0 and 1, then will it be output as a `bit` or as some sort of `integer`?

Comment: you can control it by using the CONVERT function, for example use:
CONVERT(smallint,1) , which converts 1 to a smallint.

documentation of the funktion:
https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable a return it after set in a IF/ELSE Statement like :

```
DECLARE @Result Bit

IF column =-1  
    SET @Result = 0
ELSE
    SET @Result = 1
RETURN @Result
```

[Here for more Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server) about bool values in SQL:

> In Management Studio it displays as a false/true value (at least in
> recent versions).
>
> When accessing the database through ASP.NET it will expose the field
> as a boolean value.

Hope this help you.