# Updating bool to non-nullable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for the equivalent of the query below for bit data types

```
 Sql("ALTER TABLE Table_name ALTER COLUMN column INTEGER NOT NULL");
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no equivalent, because SQL Server does not have a boolean data type.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server

Comment: BIT columns *can* be null-able though if you allow them to be... but this isn't good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE Table_name ALTER COLUMN column BIT NOT NULL");
```