# What is the difference between BIT and Boolean , Why we can use Boolean in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

What is the Difference between Bit and Boolean?

Why can't we use `boolean` in SQL Server 2017.

I tried to use `bool` in SQL query it showing error.

Comment: "*Why can't we use boolean in SQL Server 2017?"* - SQL Server simply does not support the standard `boolean` data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no boolean in SQL Server. Instead it uses `BIT` type to store `0` or `1`.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777257/how-do-you-create-a-yes-no-boolean-field-in-sql-server) for more info

Comment: This should have been a close as dupe vote instead of an answer.